# Green's function of time-dependent Stokes equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, navier-stokes

It is well known that the Green's function of a standard parabolic equation in a bounded domain, say 
\begin{align}
\partial_tG(x,y,t)-\Delta_x G(x,y,t)&=0 
&&\mbox{for}\,\,\,(x,t)\in \Omega\times{\mathbb R}_+ , \\
G(x,y,t)&=0 &&\mbox{for}\,\,\,(x,t)\in\partial\Omega\times{\mathbb R}_+ ,\\
G(x,y,0)&=\delta(x-y)
&&\mbox{for}\,\,\,x\in \Omega ,
\end{align}
with $y\in\Omega$, satisfies the following pointwise Gaussian estimate:
$$
|G(x,y,t)|\le Ct^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{t}} .
$$
Higher-order partial derivatives of Green's function satisfy 
$$
|\partial_t^m\partial_x^kG(x,y,t)|\le C_{m,k}t^{-\frac{d}{2}-m-\frac{k}{2}}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{t}} .
$$

Is there a similar Gaussian estimate for Green's function of the time-dependent Stokes equation ? The Green function of the time-dependent Stokes equation is a matrix $G_{ij}(x,y,t)$, satisfying the following equation: 
\begin{align}
\partial_t G_{ij}(x,y,t)-\Delta_x G_{ij}(x,y,t) + \partial_j P_{i}(x,y,t) &=0 
&&\mbox{for}\,\,\,(x,t)\in \Omega\times{\mathbb R}_+ ,\\
\sum_{j=1}^d\partial_j G_{ij}(x,y,t)&=0 
&&\mbox{for}\,\,\,(x,t)\in \Omega\times{\mathbb R}_+ ,\\
G_{ij}(x,y,t)&=0 &&\mbox{for}\,\,\,(x,t)\in\partial\Omega\times{\mathbb R}_+ ,\\
G_{ij}(x,y,0)&=\delta_{ij}(x-y) 
&&\mbox{for}\,\,\,x\in \Omega ,
\end{align}
where 
$$
\delta_{ij}(x-y)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\delta(x-y) &&\mbox{if}\,\,\,i=j,\\
&0 &&\mbox{if}\,\,\,i\neq j.
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

Equivalently, if we denote ${\bf G}_i(x,y,t)$ to be the $i$th row of the matrix $G_{ij}(x,y,t)$, then
\begin{align}
\partial_t {\bf G}_{i}(x,y,t)-\Delta_x {\bf G}_{i}(x,y,t) + \nabla P_{i}(x,y,t) &=0 
&&\mbox{for}\,\,\,(x,t)\in \Omega\times{\mathbb R}_+ , \\
\nabla\cdot {\bf G}_{i}(x,y,t)&=0 
&&\mbox{for}\,\,\,(x,t)\in \Omega\times{\mathbb R}_+ , \\
{\bf G}_{i}(x,y,t)&=0 &&\mbox{for}\,\,\,(x,t)\in\partial\Omega\times{\mathbb R}_+ ,\\
{\bf G}_{i}(x,y,0)&=(\delta_{i1},\delta_{i2},\delta_{i3})\,\delta(x-y)
&&\mbox{for}\,\,\,x\in \Omega .
\end{align}

The question is whether the following estimate holds ? 
$$
|G_{ij}(x,y,t)|\le Ct^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{t}} ,
$$
and
$$
|\partial_t^m\partial_x^kG_{ij}(x,y,t)|\le C_{m,k}t^{-\frac{d}{2}-m-\frac{k}{2}}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{t}} .
$$